# Create a clickable QTextEdit with a pixmap in a label as background

Tags: python, drawing, pyqt4, qtextedit, pixmap

I need my QTextEdit (or correct: QTextBrowser) to have a background image.

```
    self.background=QLabel()
    self.background.move(0,0)
    self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap("/Icons/bg-text.png"))
    self.background.show()

    self.textedit = QTextBrowser(self)

    self.background.setParent(self.textedit)
```

The problem is: The image is above the text. So I can't click on the text to set the cursor position, nor can I select the text. How can i solve this or make a workaround?

I know that this problem occurs with the image, because i have a similar one, where i make a QLabel (also with an image) that has pushButtons, and if I create the pushButtons after the image, it works (= I can click the buttons). But here with the textedit, the QTextBrowser can't be added to itself like the buttons to the QLabel. I tried to solve this by setting the parent after creating  the background, but it doesn't work.

Edit:

My ideas right now:
1: If the QLabel would be click-through-able, it would probably work. Don't know how to do that.
2: Passing the click-event to the self.textedit, same here.

Maybe those are good points to start from?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes I got it.

You can set the background image with a stylesheet, and even with a QLinearGradient over it.
Then you can click the text correctly.

```
    self.textedit.setStyleSheet("""QTextBrowser{background: QLinearGradient(x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:1,stop:0 #fff, stop: 0.9 #123);
                                                background-image: url("/home/Icons/bg-text.png");
                                                color: #3159b3}""")
```